# in org-mode, how to view TODO items for current buffer only?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In org-mode, I like to run `org-todo-list`, which displays the global todo list including all my org-agenda files. How do I view a TODO list for only the current buffer, ignoring my other org-agenda files?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `<` from the agenda menu to restrict the current agenda call to the buffer that the agenda was invoked from.  To restrict to that file for more than one call, you can use `C-c C-x <` (`org-agenda-set-restriction-lock`).  See `(info "(org) Agenda files")` for more information.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `org-show-todo-tree` to get a sparse tree view of the current buffer's TODO items. It's bound to `C-c / t` by default.

Comment: After that how can I expand only all `TODO`s?

Answer (score 9):

You could bind `org-agenda-files` dynamically to the current buffer's file and call `org-todo-list` from there:

```el
(defun org-todo-list-current-file (&optional arg)
  "Like `org-todo-list', but using only the current buffer's file."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((org-agenda-files (list (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))))
    (if (null (car org-agenda-files))
        (error "%s is not visiting a file" (buffer-name (current-buffer)))
      (org-todo-list arg))))
```

Comment: I am having following message: `Global list of TODO items of type: ALL
Available with ‘N r’: (0)[ALL]`

Comment: The let-binding of `org-agenda-files` is only good for this command and will be reverted for any additional searches, so in particular `N r` for some number N will *not* limit itself to the current file: it will be a global search through the default value of `org-agenda-files`.