# Listing the TODOs from the current file

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, todo

I was wondering whether there is a command that allows to list the TODOs (in a similar way than <kbd>C-c</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) but for the current buffer... a buffer which might not even be within the list of agenda files.

Comment: this could be what you are looking for https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/in-org-mode-how-to-view-todo-items-for-current-buffer-only/13239

Comment: Thank you @andrej I found very useful information there! Sticking with =C-c / t= !!!