# Not able to filter Global list of TODO items

Tags: org-mode

I have been using:

```
(defun org-todo-list-current-file (&optional arg)
 ;;  "Like `org-todo-list', but using only the current buffer's file."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((org-agenda-files (list (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))))
    (if (null (car org-agenda-files))
        (error "%s is not visiting a file" (buffer-name (current-buffer)))
      (org-todo-list arg))))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'org-todo-list-current-file)
```

to create a Global list of TODO items, as a shortcut key to `C-c a < t` .

I then used to be able to do

> Press ‘N r’ (e.g. ‘0 r’)

To filter by a particular TODO type.

However, for some reason, this stopped working recently. Maybe due to an upgrade of emacs. Also pressing `r` to refresh a list has stopped working.

However, if I use `C-c a < t` to create the same Global list of TODO items, then `N - r` and `r` do work.

I have been trying to figure out a solution to this and have not come up with anything.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you got that from [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/in-org-mode-how-to-view-todo-items-for-current-buffer-only). I posted a comment on the relevant  answer indicating its shortcoming in this respect.  You are better off either imitating what Org mode is doing when setting a restriction (which is somewhat complicated IIRC). I would just use a keyboard macro for `C-c a < t` instead and let Org mode do the heavy lifting.

Comment: ... except that does not seem to work.

Comment: Hi NickD thanks once again for your time and help. I just figured out that if I add the file to the list using `C-c [`, then filtering by TODO type or using `r` to do a refresh does work.

Comment: PS I did get that code from the question you refer to.

Comment: Now I would like to see if I can add some code to my code above to add the current file to the list....if you have any thoughts on that, it would be appreciated....

Comment: Not knowing elisp, I am adding `(let ((org-agenda-file-to-front (list (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))))` but getting some errors....

Comment: Also just tried `(setq org-agenda-file-to-front (list (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))))` but to no avail.....I am not finding any other code examples so kind of stuck....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    (defun ndk/org-todo-list-current-file ()
      (interactive)
      (when (derived-mode-p 'org-mode))
        (org-agenda nil "t" 'buffer))


    (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f7>zt") #'ndk/org-todo-list-current-file)
```

Since we assume that the current file is an Org mode file (it does not make any sense to ask for the TODO list of arbitrary files), the function checks that the mode of the current buffer is `org-mode` before calling `org-agenda` in a special way: it calls it with a `keys` argument of the string `"t"` (IOW asking for `org-agenda` to dispatch to the function `org-todo-list`) and with a `restriction` argument of `buffer`, restricting the agenda command to just the current buffer. This is the lisp equivalent of `C-c a < t`.

We also define the key to bind this command to in `org-mode-map` only, not globally, since it is not useful to define it globally: we cannot invoke the command unless the buffer is an Org mode buffer. Given this, we could dispense with the checking of the mode in the function, but a little paranoia never hurt (and actually, it is necessary, just in case you decide to call the function directly with `M-x ndk/org-todo-list-current-file` and not through the keybinding).

You can use any key combo that is not used. In my particular case, both `<f7>` and `<f7>z` are prefix keys, and `<f7>zt` was unused, so that's the keybinding I used, but YMMV: choose something appropriate to your setup.

If I visit an Org mode file (whether it's an agenda file or not) and call the command either with the keybinding I created, `<f7>zt`, or with `M-x ndk/org-todo-list-current-file` I get the TODO list for that file only and any subsequent `N r` invocations remain restricted to that file only.

Comment: That works perfectly :) This comment box says to avoid "Thanks" but I am very grateful for your help!

Comment: Thanks also for taking the time to describe how the code works - I learned something :)