# Programmatically use org-tags-view to search in current subtree

Tags: org-mode, search, org-tags, narrowing

I am looking for a way to programmatically search for headings in the current subtree. More specifically, I have a vocabulary file, in which I store words I need to learn. Each word is a subtree in itself and has the property `LAST_PRACTICED_DATE`.

Interactively I would usually do the following:

1. `C-c a < < m`
2. Enter my search query, something like: `LAST_PRACTICED_DATE<"<2023-09-24>"-TODO="DONE"`
3. `Ret`

And I would get the vocabulary that I did not yet mark "done" and that I practiced before some date, according to the property (for which I have a custom procedure for updating, which I mapped to `C-x l`, `l` for "last").

Here is an example of what a part of my document looks like:

```
* HSK 3                                                                         :hsk_3:3:

** well known                                                                  :wellknown:

*** Words

**** DONE bike / bicycle
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_PRACTICED_DATE: [2023-10-01 Sun]
:END:
***** zìxíngchē
****** 自行车

**** VERIFY easy
:PROPERTIES:
:LAST_PRACTICED_DATE: [2023-10-02 Mon]
:END:
***** róngyì
****** 容易

** somewhat known                                                              :somewhatknown:

(more words here!)

** not known                                                                   :notknown:

(more words here!)
```

(`VERIFY` is a TODO status. I specified it at the top of the file.)

Now I would like to put all of that into an elisp source block instead.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
(save-excursion
  (save-restriction
    (org-previous-visible-heading 1)
    (let ((elem (org-element-at-point)))
      (let ((start (org-element-property :begin elem))
            (end (org-element-property :end elem)))
        (message "start at: " (number-to-string start))
        (message "end at: " (number-to-string end))
        (narrow-to-region start end)
        (org-tags-view nil "LAST_PRACTICED_DATE<\"<2023-10-01 Sun>\"-TODO=\"DONE\"")))))
```

This I put in an elisp source block directly under the heading `well known`, so that it should narrow the search to that subtree.

However, when I run that, the search is not narrowed to the subtree, but instead searches the whole document or at least a higher level subtree instead and shows results from `somewhat known` or `not known`. Also maybe noteworthy is, that the calls to `(message ...)` result in only the text but no numbers being printed in the `*Messages*` buffer. But I don't know how to inspect the `start` and `end` values in other ways or how to print the whole `elem`.

I thought this code would work, because I found some snippet in the code of `org-tags-view` itself:

```
(save-excursion
        (save-restriction
          (if (eq buffer org-agenda-restrict)
              (narrow-to-region org-agenda-restrict-begin
                    org-agenda-restrict-end)
            (widen))
          (setq rtn (org-scan-tags 'agenda
                       matcher
                       org--matcher-tags-todo-only))
          (setq rtnall (append rtnall rtn))))
```

So I thought narrowing before matching would do the trick.

It seems I am doing something wrong though.

How can I implement this procedure?

Comment: `org-tags-view`'s doc string says: `Show all headlines for all ‘org-agenda-files’ matching a TAGS criterion.` so unless you restrict things further (to the current file, as well as to the current subtree), it's not going to give you what you want. Have you tried `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer` instead? I think it's much more likely to  give you what you want. Or maybe `org-match-sparse-tree` instead of `org-tags-view` in your code above.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for the pointers. Isn't `org-tags-view` invoked when I press `C-c a < < m`? I thought it should be somehow trivial to do the same programmatically. Maybe it is not.

Comment: It is not: setting the restriction involves some voodoo that `org-tags-view` does not know anything about. You might want to check *how* `org-agenda` calls `org-tags-view` and how the restriction is set before it does that (there are global variables involved, including one that is attached as a property to the property list of `org-agenda-files`, which makes it a bit tricky to understand - and I don't quite understand it well enough to provide an answer at this point).

Comment: I thought that you might be able to use `org-agenda` to call `org-tags-view`, since it knows how to set the resriction - see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/64606/14825 - but the problem there is that there is no way to pass the `match` argument to `org-tags-view` that way: you can only type it in interactively.  So the two requirements (set the restriction *and* specify the match programatically) require a stretch that the code is not quite capable of making. Interesting problem!

Comment: @NickD Thanks for that research. Guess I opened up a pretty deep rabit hole.